# get_posts in meta box dropdown not showing latest posts

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta, get-posts, wpalchemy

I’ve got a metabox I set up using WPAlchemy that allows authors to add a link to an associated post.  It’s been working fine for months but now for some reason the dropdown with the appropriate posts isn’t updating.  Here’s the code in the custom post meta php file:

```
<p>

<?php $mb->the_field(‘product_video_ID’); ?>
<select name=”<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>”>
<option value=”">None</option>

<?php

global $thispost;
$myposts = get_posts(‘numberposts=5000&offset=1′);

foreach($myposts as $thispost) :
if (in_category(“Product Videos”, $thispost)) {
?>
<option value=”<?php echo $thispost->ID; ?>” <?php $mb->the_select_state($thispost->ID);?> ><?php echo get_the_title($thispost->ID); ?></option>

<?php } ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php setup_postdata($thispost);?>
</select>
</p>
```

I tried adding a couple test posts in the Product Videos category and they didn’t show, either.  I  commented the lines that filtered for that category and the Meta box dropdown updated to show every post… except the one I wanted and the new test ones.  Anybody have any idea what might be going on?  Is there some part of the machinery here that isn’t updating that I should fix?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get the posts, since `get_posts()` also makes use of it:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'product-videos',
    'posts_per_page' => 5000, // or -1 if you want all
    'offset' => 1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <option value=”<?php the_ID(); ?>” <?php $mb->the_select_state(get_the_ID());?> ><?php echo get_the_title(get_the_ID()); ?></option>
        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks - using WP_Query ended up causing all sorts of bugs, but you also hit the nail on the head on the issue - I was querying only 5000 posts, and the issue started because the site had surpassed 5000 so the new ones weren't showing.  Simply changing 5000 in my code to -1 fixed the issue :-)